# Dynamically Script Loading Zendesk Widget

Tags: javascript, zendesk, dynamic-script-loading

I have been trying to save resources on the page by not loading the Zendesk Widget unless required.

If i manually add to a page the following tag everything works just fine:

```
<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=[MyKey]> </script>
```

As part of my page i have somewhere a div tag always present:

```
<div id="ze-snippet"> </div>
```

What i would like to have is, to do a "dynamic script load" of that `<script>` tag when a user clicks a button.

My current attempt looks like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var zendeskWidgetOn = false;
  document.getElementById('enable-zendesk-widget').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    if (!zendeskWidgetOn) {
      zendeskWidgetOn=true;
      (function(d, script) {
        script = d.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = function(){
          console.log('script finished loading ...');
        };
        script.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=[my key]';
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }(document));
    }
  }, false);
};
```

The error i keep getting and i can't for the life of me figure out how to work around it is: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have the widget script load only upon clicking the button, you just have to insert this to your html:

```
<script>
  function loadZendeskWidget() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.id = 'ze-snippet';
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<key>';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
</script>
```

Just replace "key" with your own widget key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it did push me on the right path to getting my answer, yet i can't understand why your solution works and mine does not as yours is exactly the same thing as i did , only mine was an IIFE so i can have my things nicely wrapped in a closure also yours is in a stand alone <script> tag. Basically what i did it was having the method you posted in a <script> tag and then all the other dependencies rely on it being there and fire it accordingly .... and boom , it worked. Cheers mate !

Comment: This is the way to go if you're using react and trying to apply custom "zESettings", such as offsetting the vertical height! Custom settings must be set BEFORE the zendesk script loads.